# rename file to specific name before upload php

Tags: php, rename

I have a form where the user can upload a jpeg image but I have an issue renaming the file to a specific name. (my code doesnt delete the old name and adds the new name after the extension example of result: originalname.jpgnewname.jpg )

Below is my img-upload-processor.php

```
<?php
$temp = explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name']);
$extension = end($temp);
$targetfolder = "image/";
$newname="newname";
$filename = $newname . '.' . $extension;
$targetfolder = $targetfolder   . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;

$ok=1;

$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];

if ($file_type=="image/jpeg") {

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder .$filename))
    {

        echo "<span class='green'>New Logo  uploaded</span>.<br>";

    }
    else {

        echo "<span class='red'>Problem uploading file </span>.";

    }

}
else {

     echo "You may only upload <span class='red'> jpeg </span> images.<br>";

}
?>
```

Comment: This is petty, but I recommend calling the target directory "images" instead of "image".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$targetfolder = $targetfolder   . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;
```

When you are creating the `$targetfolder` variable, you are adding the base name to it for some reason. Thus if the file was called `something.jpg` and the target folder was `/a/b/c/` you'll get `/a/b/c/something.jpg` as the value of `$targetfolder`.

Later in your code you add your own file name again:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder .$filename))
```

So I think you'll be happy if you remove `$targetfolder = $targetfolder   . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;` all together.